# Child collection won't insert with parent object in EF6

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 (6.1.3 I think) in a web api application. For some odd reason my child collection navigation will not insert when I insert a parent object something in a disconnected context scenario like below:

```
var child1 = new Child { /*fill values */ };
var child2 = new Child { /*fill values */ };
var children = new List<Child>();
children.Add(child1);
children.Add(child2);

var parent = new Parent
{
    // fill other properties

    Children = children
}

dbContext.Parents.Add(parent);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? I thought adding an object to a context would automatically add all children in the entity graph. Also trying to get this to work as part of a Repository pattern. Super confused about the whole thing.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Always hard to tell with these mock up questions. I assume (and hope) the real application has different entities. It's always better to show the real thing because you may have left out code that you don't realize causes side effects.

Comment: You’re correct that this is just a mock because I’m using the repository pattern (which is not working too but that’s for later) however I’m trying to know conceptually whether it is true that when you “add” a parent to the context i.e make it aware that it would by default also add its child objects and child collections. If not then what is the correct approach. I can totally attach my code sample if you think would give you a better perspective in responding to my question.

Comment: Also if you can tell me whether using a generic repository pattern a good fit with entity framework and how in the future can I easily switch to CQRS if even possible.